# Jest + Enzyme tests written in CoffeeScript

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, jestjs, enzyme

Is it possible to write Enzyme tests in CoffeeScript?

```
// sample.test.coffee

React = require "react"
ReactDOM = require 'react-dom'
shallow = require('enzyme').shallow

test 'render', () ->
  expect(shallow(`<span/>`).contains('does not matter')).toBe(true)
```

With the above `yarn test` throws the `Unexpected token <` error. And points to the opening of the `<span/>`. I'm assuming I'm missing some preprocessing that should be set up in the `jest.transform` configuration? Or is it something else?

Comment: The issue here is likely the use of the back tick, which is not passed through to the generated Javascript. 

You may have better luck using `React.createElement` syntax or passing it through as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, the preprocessor needs to be set up correctly in Jest configuration:

test/javascript/preprocessor.js:

```
const coffee = require('coffeescript');
const babelJest = require('babel-jest');

module.exports = {
    process: (src, path, ...rest) => {
        if (coffee.helpers.isCoffee(path)) {
            // Compile the CoffeeScript files to JSX
            compiled_to_js = coffee.compile(src, {bare: true});
            return babelJest.process(compiled_to_js, path, ...rest);
        }
        return src;
    }
};
```

package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "coffee"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).(js|coffee)?(x)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      ".*": "./test/javascript/preprocessor.js"
    },
    {...}
}
```